# Visual Studio 2010 events button has disappeared

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Hi I have been working with visual studio 2010 ultimate all day developing an asp.net webforms application.
I just realized that on the properties for controls window the button for events is missing , the one that looks like a thunderbolt.

An hour ago that button was there and now somehow it has disapeared and I can't figure out how to make it visible again.

I have tryed reseting the visual studio settings and reseting the computer but nothing worked

How can I get the button back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. This helped me.
 1.Restart visual studio 2010.
 2.Click and select a control in markup page(.aspx)(like 
 3.After selecting , Click "View" in menu and select "Property window".

Check the property box, Thunderbolt ll be available. It just happened for me!

---

If the above solution not working go on with this!

```
1.Select design view in markup(.aspx)
2.Select any individual control like a button or label..
3.Now, you will be able to see a ">" button on the right side? Click it.
4.Remember to select only one control./.now check your property window! Whoohoo..
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually while the solution above works, it puts you through more steps than you need. You can resolve this famous disappearing thunderbolt by simply clicking on Design view, and then clicking back on Source view, then clicking again to select the control in source view.

The Thunderbolt icon and events for the control will magically reappear.

You do not need to restart Visual Studio, and you do not need to select anything while in Design view.

And now, for my RANT about this annoying bug:

Even though this is easy to resolve, it is a MAJOR inconvenience to developers in my opinion, because we have to do this silly workaround all the freaking time.

This is in fact a BUG in Visual Studio. It has existed since at least Visual Studio 2010 (many users have reported it here and in MS forums across this and all later versions of VS). I have confirmed that this bug still exists in the latest build of Visual Studio 2022. So clearly MS has no plans to fix it.

[Rant Mode Off]

Cheers,
-=Cameron